# putting xml elements in correct order for validation using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I make modifications to an XML object using SimpleXML library and output it. But, order of the elements or attributes are not correct in the output and it does not validate with the schema.

Is there way to change order of the elements to be valid with xml schema ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to re-order nodes using SimpleXML that I know of. Your best option may be to convert it to a DOMDocument object and then use the DOMNode->insertBefore() method to insert a new DOMNode before another one.

A good example of what you're looking to do may be http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php.

source: [Reorder XML nodes with php and simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522599/reorder-xml-nodes-with-php-and-simplexml)

Comment: i think, i need more complex solution. A function that will take xml and schema as input and produce correct xml document as output. I guess there must be some tools doing this.

Comment: After you have manipulated the dom, you can output it to XML using $dom->asXML(); see http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

Comment: i guess with simplexml this can be done. You create the target XML in correct order with blank values. read source xml and assign elements to target. After you may delete blank elements in target.

Comment: but I was looking for a ready made solution. If not  I will try to code.