# Re-ordering nodes in an xml via jquery ui drag and drop

Tags: php, jquery, xml, jquery-ui

I hope someone can help me here...

I am currently working on a small piece of code that will allow me to re-order nodes in an xml file via a jquery ui sortable interface.

Take the following xml file:

```
<Root>
   <Page1>
     <content>
       This is content 1
     </content>
   </Page1>
   <Page2>
     <content>
       This is content 2
     </content>
   </Page2>
   <Page3>
     <content>
       This is content 3
     </content>
   </Page3>
</Root>
```

I have been able to use php to to build a drag and drop interface based on the number of nodes in the xml file. What I am trying to achieve is a way of saving the new order of the xml files when the data is passed from the sortable interface.  From the jquery ui, I can get the ids required and I am able to pass that onto php.  My main issue is how to manipulate the xml file to get the following result:

```
<Root>
   <Page1>
     <content>
       This is content 3
     </content>
   </Page1>
   <Page2>
     <content>
       This is content 1
     </content>
   </Page2>
   <Page3>
     <content>
       This is content 2
     </content>
   </Page3>
</Root>
```

Hope this is making sense and I hope someone has an idea of how I can achieve this.  Is it possible to do this with DOMDocument as I believe SimpleXML is not powerful enough to handle such a task.

My day would be made if a solution can be attained.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to parse it and write to a new XML file. Is it possible to change the XML structure to keep track of their position, for example; `<Page position="1"><content>....` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the XML structure has to remain the same (which is a pain at best)..

Comment: Let the form post an array with `<input name="position[]">`, get the XML into an array, parse `Page1` for it's position (1), refill a new array with the correct sorting then that array to XML and overwrite XML file. Would not recommend this with large data sets and high traffic sites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reorder XML nodes with php and simplexml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522599/reorder-xml-nodes-with-php-and-simplexml)